# Polymorphism: a constant versus a function

Tags: haskell, types, polymorphism

I'm new to Haskell and come across a slightly puzzling example for me in the *Haskell Programming from First Principles* book. At the end of Chapter 6 it suddenly occurred to me that the following doesn't work:

```
constant :: (Num a) => a
constant = 1.0
```

However, the following works fine:

```
f :: (Num a) => a -> a
f x = 3*x
```

I can input any numerical value for `x` into the function `f` and nothing will break. It's not constrained to taking integers. This makes sense to me intuitively. But the example with the constant is totally confusing to me.

Over on a reddit [thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/HaskellBook/comments/50kzh7/ch6_match_the_types/) for the book it was explained (paraphrasing) that the reason why the constant example doesn't work is that the type declaration forces the value of `constant` to only be things which aren't more specific than `Num`. So trying to assign a value to it which is from a subclass of `Num` like `Fractional` isn't kosher.

If that explanation is correct, then am I wrong in thinking that these two examples seem completely opposites of each other? In one case, the type declaration forces the value to be as general as possible. In the other case, the accepted values for the function can be *anything* that implements `Num`.

Can anyone set me straight on this?

Comment: Not sure how this fits in with your understanding, but: your definition for `constant` works fine with the `NumDecimals` extension turned on, and even without it, `constant :: Num a => a; constant = 1` is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @DanielWagner: I see that `constant = 1` works fine. I guess the crux of my misunderstanding is that I don't really understand why `constant = 1.0` doesn't work...

Comment: In the second example, try changing the `3` to `3.0`.

Comment: because being a `Num` implies only `+`, `-`, `*`, `abs`, `negate`, `signum` and `fromInteger`. `fromInteger` is the clue here - everything that is `Num` may be constructed from `Integer`, but `1.0` is not an `Integer`. To use `1.0` you would need `fromRational` which is a member of `Fractional` - thus not guaranteed to be in every `Num`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can sometimes help to read types as a game played between two actors, the implementor of the type and the user of the type. To do a good job of explaining this perspective, we have to introduce something that Haskell hides from you by default: we will add binders for all type variables. So your types would actually become:

```
constant :: forall a. Num a => a
f :: forall a. Num a => a -> a
```

Now, we will read type formation rules thusly:

- `forall a. t` means: the caller chooses a type `a`, and the game continues as `t`
- `c => t` means: the caller shows that constraint `c` holds, and the game continues as `t`
- `t -> t'` means: the caller chooses a value of type `t`, and the game continues as `t'`
- `t` (where `t` is a monomorphic type such as a bare variable or `Integer` or similar) means: the implementor produces a value of type `a`

We will need a few other details to truly understand things here, so I will quickly say them here:

- When we write a number with no decimal points, the compiler implicitly converts this to a call to `fromInteger` applied to the `Integer` produced by parsing that number. We have `fromInteger :: forall a. Num a => Integer -> a`.
- When we write a number with decimal points, the compiler implicitly converts this to a call to `fromRational` applied to the `Rational` produced by parsing that number. We have `fromRational :: forall a. Fractional a => Rational -> a`.
- The `Num` class includes the method `(*) :: forall a. Num a => a -> a -> a`.

Now let's try to walk through your two examples slowly and carefully.

```
constant :: forall a. Num a => a
constant = 1.0 {- = fromRational (1 % 1) -}
```

The type of `constant` says: the caller chooses a type, shows that this type implements `Num`, and then the implementor must produce a value of that type. Now the implementor tries to play his own game by calling `fromRational :: Fractional a => Rational -> a`. He chooses the same type the caller did, and then makes an attempt to show that this type implements `Fractional`. Oops! He can't show that, because the only thing the caller proved to him was that `a` implements `Num` -- which doesn't guarantee that `a` also implements `Fractional`. Dang. So the implementor of `constant` isn't allowed to call `fromRational` at that type.

Now, let's look at `f`:

```
f :: forall a. Num a => a -> a
f x = 3*x {- = fromInteger 3 * x -}
```

The type of `f` says: the caller chooses a type, shows that the type implements `Num`, and chooses a value of that type. The implementor must then produce another value of that type. He is going to do this by playing his own game with `(*)` and `fromInteger`. In particular, he chooses the same type the caller did. But now `fromInteger` and `(*)` only demand that he prove that this type is an instance of `Num` -- so he passes off the proof the caller gave him of this and saves the day! Then he chooses the `Integer` `3` for the argument to `fromInteger`, and chooses the result of this and the value the caller handed him as the two arguments to `(*)`. Everybody is satisfied, and the implementor gets to return a new value.

The point of this whole exposition is this: the `Num` constraint in both cases is enforcing *exactly* the same thing, namely, that whatever type we choose to instantiate `a` at must be a member of the `Num` class. It's just that in the definition `constant = 1.0` being in `Num` isn't enough to do the operations we've written, whereas in `f x = 3*x` being in `Num` *is* enough to do the operations we've written. And since the operations we've chosen for the two things are so different, it should not be *too* surprising that one works and the other doesn't!

Comment: Ahhhhhh. I see. So to sum up: basically, the implicit call to `FromRational` is the issue here. `Num` doesn't provide that, so that's the reason why it fails. Is that correct?

Comment: ...and in the example for `f` the fact that the *function* can take any number input makes sense, because as long as the function definition for `f` passes the type signature test, then the constraint on the function input remains `Num a => a`, which is general enough to take any number. This makes sense to me now, but please correct if I'm wrong.

Comment: @gogurt That sounds basically right to me! Note, though, that for the function, the constraint `Num a` is not merely on the argument, which it sounds like you sort of believe with your sentence, "the constraint on the function input remains `Num a => a`". In fact, the constraint `Num a` says that you have to pick a `Num` instance; then once you've done that, you get a function of type `a -> a` for that instance. The type `foo :: (forall a. Num a => a) -> ...`, which sounds like what you're trying to describe, is a very different one!

Answer (score 4):

When you have a polymorphic value, the caller chooses which concrete type to use. The [Haskell report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch6.html#x13-1350006.4) defines the type of numeric literals, namely:

> integer and floating literals have the typings (Num a) => a and
>   (Fractional a) => a, respectively

`3` is an integer literal so has type `Num a => a` and `(*)` has type `Num a => a -> a -> a` so `f` has type `Num a => a -> a`.

In contrast, `3.0` has type `Fractional a => a`. Since `Fractional` is a subclass of `Num` your  type signature for `constant` is invalid since the caller could choose a type for `a` which is `Num` but not `Fractional` e.g. `Int` or `Integer`.

Answer (score 1):

They don't mean the opposite - they mean exactly the same ("as general as possible"). Typeclass gives you all guarantees that you can rely upon - if typeclass `T` provides function `f`, you can use it for all instances of `T`, but even if some of these instances are members of `G` (providing `g`) as well, requiring to be of `T` typeclass is not sufficient to call `g`.

In your case this means:

Members of `Num` are guaranteed to provide conversion from integers (i.e. default type for integral values, like `1` or `1000`) - with `fromInteger` function.

However, they are not guaranteed to provide conversion from rational numbers (like `1.0`) - `Fractional` typeclass does provide this as `fromRational` function, but it doesn't really matter, as you use only `Num`.